# Tkinter комманда вызывается до нажатия на кнопку

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from gtts import gTTS
import sys
Entry_quantity = 0
def Print_text():
    Lbl1 = Label(text = 'Hello World!', font ='arail 10')
    Lbl1.place(x=200,y=240)
def app_Run():

    Win = Tk()
    Win.geometry('500x450')
    # Эта кнопка должна при нажатии выводить текст, но не выводит. Текст выводится заранее
    Convert_Btn = Button(Win, text='Convert', width=10, height=2, bg='gray', fg='black', font='arail 10',command = Print_text())
    Convert_Btn.place(x=0, y=3)

    Sort_Btn = Button(Win, text='Sorting', width=10, height=2, bg='gray', fg='black', font='bold 9')
    Sort_Btn.place(x=0, y=50)

    Quantity_Btn_plus = Button(Win, text='十', width=10, height=2, bg='green', fg='white', font='bold 8' )
    Quantity_Btn_plus.place(x=0, y=100)



    Quantity_Btn_minus = Button(Win, text='一', width=10, height=2, bg='red', fg='black', font='bold 8')
    Quantity_Btn_minus.place(x=0, y=150)

    Chn_entr = Entry(Win)
    Chn_entr.place(x=130, y=5)

    Ru_Entr = Entry(Win)
    Ru_Entr.place(x=265, y=5)
    Win.mainloop()
###############################################################################


if __name__ =='__main__':
    app_Run()
    print(Entry_quantity)
```

Comment: `command = Print_text()` - скобочки уберите, чтобы не вызывалась.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А можно вопрос ? Как можно реализовать функцию, что бы по нажатию кнопки окно Enter дублировалось, и создавалость еще одно окно ввода ?